# MySQL - ORDER BY date, then collate by title

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I wish to sort my results into groups (but not `GROUP BY`, just collated) of column title, and within each group they would be sorted by date. The groups would be ascending in date.

I thought a simple `ORDER BY date, title` would suffice, but this does not work as expected.

You can see my data here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/658f7c/11 The rows with the message column containing `Old (...)` should appear first, while the ones containing `New (...)` should appear later (within the groups, they should be sorted by date).

The expected output should be below. Note: the date should always be ascending.

```
Title  |  Message     | Date
-----------------------------
Old    |  Old (One)   | 0001
Old    |  Old (Two)   | 0002
Old    |  Old (Three) | 0029
New    |  New (One)   | 0002
New    |  New (Two)   | 0003
New    |  New (Three) | 0004
```

Comment: `ORDER BY title desc, post_date asc`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT title, message, post_id, user_id, post_date
FROM `table`
ORDER BY title DESC, post_date ASC
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/658f7c/13)**